# Programmr "String Split" Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I am using the site Programmr.com to help practice my java. Well I am stuck on a string exercise that I can't figure out for the life of me and was hoping you all could help. One thing to note is that I am trying to solve this with only the knowledge I should have so far, which is only variables and 
strings. The problem goes like this:

A String variable, fullName, contains a name in the following format:
first name  last name (single blank)

Extract the first name into the String variable firstName and the last name into the String variable lastName.
Assume the variables have been declared and fullName already initialized. You may also declare any other necessary variables.

```
import java.util.Scanner;   
public class namessplit {  



public static void main(String args[]){   

    String fullName="";   
    String[] str;   
    String firstName="";  
    String lastName="";  
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);   
        System.out.println("Enter the full name:");   
        fullName=scanner.nextLine();    

    System.out.println("The names after split is:");   
    ///{  
     //write your code here  
     //start  




     //end            
    ///}   

    System.out.println(firstName+"' "+lastName);   



}     
}
```

Comment: Familiarize yourself with methods of `String` class.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. One condition of asking questions is that you've researched the issue you are having. So, where have you looked and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use split() method

```
import java.util.Scanner;   

public class namessplit{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String fullName="";   
        String[] str;   
        String firstName="";  
        String lastName="";  
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);   
        System.out.println("Enter the full name:");   
        fullName=scanner.nextLine();    
        System.out.println("The names after split is:");   
        str=fullName.split(" ");
        firstName=str[0];
        lastName=str[1];
        System.out.println(firstName+"' "+lastName);   
    }
}
```

OR

If you want to use charAt() method

```
import java.util.Scanner;   

public class namessplit{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String fullName="";   
        String[] str;   
        String firstName="";  
        String lastName="";  
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);   
        System.out.println("Enter the full name:");   
        fullName=scanner.nextLine();    
        System.out.println("The names after split is:");   
        int i;
        for( i=0;i<fullName.length();i++){
           if (fullName.charAt(i)==' '){
               break;
           }
        }

        firstName=fullName.substring(0,i+1);
        lastName=fullName.substring(i+1);
        System.out.println(firstName+"' "+lastName);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by "accepting" the answer. But you solutions was VERY helpful. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That could also work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;    

public class namessplit{   

    public static void main(String args[]){   
        String fullName="";     
        String[] str;       
        String firstName="";    
        String lastName="";  

        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);   
        System.out.println("Enter the full name:");   
        fullName=scanner.nextLine();    
        System.out.println("The names after split is:");    

        int spacePos = fullName.indexOf(" ");
        firstName = fullName.substring(0,spacePos);
        lastName = fullName.substring(spacePos,fullName.length() );

        System.out.println(firstName+"' "+lastName);   
    } 

}
```